# Python:why 10 / -7 is -2 in python?

Tags: python

I am new to programming.When I find this strange result while I learning python.

```
>>> 10/-7
-2
```

Comment: That's not strange, that's normal. ;) In Python 2, `10/-7` does floor division, but it's better to write it as `10//-7`, which explicitly says that you're doing floor division. Floor division always rounds down, i.e., towards negative infinity.

Comment: If you are learning Python, you should be learning Python 3, not Python 2, which has an official EOL date of 2020.